# Is there a way to quickly find (and remove) unused tags in Remember the Milk?

Tags: remember-the-milk

Over the years, I have accumulated nearly 400 tags in Remember the Milk, as I have changed from one tagging system to another while learning how to best use the service and while cycling through various personal projects. Many of these tags are no longer used.

Is there a quick way to find all (or large batches of) the unused tags in my account, so that I can remove them relatively quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting what I believe is the correct answer to my own question...

No, there is no way in the user interface (website or mobile) to find large batches of unused tags which could then be deleted in bulk.

In [Best way to permanently delete unused tags?](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/forums/help/14449/) (Remember the Milk support forum), a user asked about the best way to remove unused tags. The answer given was to find the tag which you know is unused and delete it. There was no indication of another way to do the deletions in bulk.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings->Tags, mark the checkbox next to each tag to be deleted, and then select "delete tag" from the dropdown menu at the top of the list. You can see if a tag is in use (for either complete and/or incomplete tasks) by hovering over the name of the tag.